# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.DS_Store'

Tags: python, macos, mac

Пытался наладить сортировку по возрастанию, но для этого нужно привести все документы к виду int. При исполнении кода, появляется ошибка. Я пытался через терминал удалить все имеющиеся документы .DS_Store, пытался отключить их появление впредь. В директории в которой я работаю - их не видно (отображение скрытых файлов включено), но ошибка все равно не исчезает.

Подскажите пожалуйста как быть? К сожалению нет возможности работать на Windows или Linux, под рукой только рабочий Макбук и всё.[![

```
import json
import os



def write_block(name, amount, to_whom, prev_hash = ''):

    blockchain_dir = os.curdir + '/blockchain/'     # ./blockchain/test

    files = os.listdir(blockchain_dir)
    files = sorted([str(i) for i in files])

    print(files)

    # data = {'name': name,
    #       'amount': amount,
    #       'to_whom': to_whom, 
    #       'hash': prev_hash}

    # with open(blockchain_dir + 'test', 'w') as file:
    #   json.dump(data, file, indent = 4, ensure_ascii = False)



def main():
    write_block(name = 'ivan', amount = 2, to_whom = 'katya')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
][1]][1]
```

[image: Неверная сортировка]
[image: Выдаваемая ошибка]

Comment: [Про скрытые файлы](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7099342) как их не обрабатывать `listdir`

Comment: `int()` используется для конвертации в число, что вы пытались добиться его использованием с названиями файлов? Для сортировки используется функция `sorted`: `sorted(files)`, или sort: `files.sort()`

Comment: При сортировке в том виде в котором они представлены сейчас - выдается неправильная сортировка : 1, 11, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5 ..... 1.

Поэтому сперва пытался привести их к целым числам, чтобы дальнейшая сортировка была корректна.

Comment: Можно сделать фильтрацию и сортировку для вашей коллекции: `items = sorted(filter(str.isdecimal, items), key=int)`. Но я бы лучше перед сортировкой удалил бы ненужные элементы, тогда останется только: `items = sorted(items, key=int)`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте построить примерно такую логику

```
def get_files():
    files = os.listdir(blockchain_dir)
    for file in files
        if file != '.DS_Store'
         return ([int(i) for i in files])
```